# Как записать количество посещений вместе с IP в файл?

Tags: php, массивы, функции, циклы

Подскажите, как записывать количество посещений рядом с ip через тире в файл

```
$file_ip = file('ips.txt');//Файл с айпи и счетчиком становится массивом.
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];//Айпи зашедшего.
if(in_array($ip, $file_ip)) {//Если внутри файла уже есть этот айпи 
    echo "Вы уже посетили это место.";//вместо echo - +1 к количеству посещений.
}

//Если файл пустой, почему то создается пустая строка, а потом уже айпи.

else { //Если же нет,
    file_put_contents('ips.txt', $ip."\n", FILE_APPEND);//записываем айпи
}
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: начать с того, что бы при новом посещении записывать не `$ip . "\n"` , а `{$ip}-1\n`. потом подумать, как считыва такой файл проверять in_array, и провести какие-то промежуточные действия чтобы преобразовать это к структуре ключ(ip) - значение и переписать сохранение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php
//Файл с айпи и счетчиком становится массивом.
$ipsList = ( file_exists('ips.txt') && is_readable('ips.txt') ? file('ips.txt') : [] );
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];//Айпи зашедшего.
$exists = false; //флаг что мы нашли в массиве запись с указанным IP
//Массив? 
if( is_array( $ipsList ) && count( $ipsList ) > 0 ) {
    //Бежим по каждой строке файла
    for( $i = 0; $i < count($ipsList); $i++ ) {
        $ipsList[$i] = trim( $ipsList[$i] ); //убираем "\n" в конце строки
        //Так как каждая строка в файле у нас в виде ip - count то разбиваем ее по "-"
        if ( $ipsList[$i] != '' && preg_match('/-/', $ipsList[$i]) ) {
            $pcs = explode('-', $ipsList[$i]);
            //Первый элемент получивашегося массива - ip, второй счетчик
            if ( is_array( $pcs ) && count( $pcs ) >= 2 && trim( $pcs[0] ) == $ip ) {
                $ipsList[$i] = trim( $pcs[0] ).' - '.( intval( trim( $pcs[1] ) ) + 1 );
                $exists = true;
                //break; //не делаем break чтобы у каждой строки массива сработал trim() иначе у нас будут в файле пустые строки
            }
        }
    }
} 
if ( !$exists )  { 
    $ipsList[] = $ip.' - 1';
}

if ( !file_exists('ips.txt') || is_writeable('ips.txt') ) { 
    file_put_contents('ips.txt', implode("\n", $ipsList ) );//записываем айпи
}
```